# Prove that $A=\{x\in X:$ there is a simple chain consisting of members of $\mathscr O$ that connects $a$ and $x\}$ is open

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\mathscr T)$ be a topological space and let $a,b \in X$. A **simple chain** connecting $a$ and $b$ is a finite set $U_1,U_2,...,U_n$ of open sets such that $a\in U_1\setminus U_2$, $b\in U_n\setminus U_{n-1}$, and each $i,j=1,2,...,n, U_i\cap U_j \neq \emptyset$ iff $|i-j|\leq 1.$

> Let $\mathscr O$ is an open cover of $X$. Then $A=\{x\in X:$ there is
>   a simple chain consisting of members of $\mathscr O$ that connects $a$
>   and $x\}$ is open.

My attempt:-
Let $x\in A$, I need to find $(x\in U)\in \mathscr T:U\subset A$. $x\in A$ means  there is a simple chain consisting of members of $\mathscr O$ that connects $a$
 and $x.$ That is there is a finite set $U_1,U_2,...,U_n\in \mathscr O$ of open sets such that $a\in U_1\setminus U_2$, $x\in U_n\setminus U_{n-1}$, and each $i,j=1,2,...,n, U_i\cap U_j \neq \emptyset$ iff $|i-j|\leq 1.$ How do I get $A$ is open from here? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in A$, and let $U_n$ be the last open set in a chain $U_1,...,U_n$ connecting $a$ and $x$.

Then $U_n$ is an open neighborhood of $x$.

To prove $A$ is open, it suffices to prove that $U_n\subseteq A$.

Let $y\in U_n$.

We want to show that $y\in A$.

If $n=1$, the chain $U_1$ connects $a$ and $y$, hence $y\in A$.

Suppose $n > 1$.

If $y\not\in U_{n-1}$, the chain $U_1,...,U_n$ connects $a$ and $y$, hence $y\in A$.

Suppose $y\in U_{n-1}$.

If $n=2$, the chain $U_1$ and connects $a$ and $y$, hence $y\in A$.

If $n > 2$, then since $y\in U_n$, it follows that $y\not\in U_{n-2}$ (since $U_n$ and $U_{n-2}$ are disjoint), hence the chain $U_1,...,U_{n-1}$ connects $a$ and $y$, so we get $y\in A$.

Thus, in all cases, we have $y\in A$.

It follows that $U_n\subseteq A$.

Therefore $A$ is open.

Comment: Let $x\in A$, and let $U_n$ be the last open set in a chain $U_1,...,U_n$ connecting $a$ and $x$.

Then $U_n$ is an open neighborhood of $x$.

To prove $A$ is open, it suffices to prove that $U_n\subseteq A$.

Let $y\in U_n$.

We want to show that $y\in A$.
Let  $V_1=U_1,...,V_n=U_n$ ,$V_1,V_2,...,V_n$ is the desired members of $\mathscr O$ such that it is a chain connecting $y$ and $a$. Right? So, $y \in A$.

Comment: @Math geek: No, it depends on $y$; there are cases.

Comment: Why do we need cases?

Comment: @Math geek: As shown in my answer, to connect $a$ and $y$, you can use the chain for $x$, but ending it at either $U_n$ or $U_{n-1}$, depending on whether $y\in U_n{\,\setminus\,}U_{n-1}$ or $y\in U_n\cap U_{n-1}$.

Comment: okay. Thank you.

Comment: $ y∈U_n  \setminus U_{n−1}$, then $y\in A$ or $y∈U_n∩U_{n−1}$, So $y\in U_{n-1}$. Again, If $ y∈U_{n-1}  \setminus U_{n−2}$, then $y\in A$ or $y∈U_{n-1}∩U_{n−2}$.  repeating the above argument. right?

Comment: No. We're assuming $y\in U_n$. Since the chain is a simple chain, $y$ _can't_ be in $U_{n-2}$.

Comment: Even $\cup_{i=1}^n U_i \subset A$. I think this is the simlest proof. right?